# Access Query for record with highest id

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access, how should I write a query that selects the record with the highest ID from a table?

I have tried a lot but could not find a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here are two:

```
Select * 
from yourTable 
where ID = (Select max(ID) as highestID from your table)
```

Or

```
Select top 1 * 
from yourTable
order by ID desc
```

It's possible that the second example will return more than one record if your IDs are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `MAX` function

```
Select MAX(ID) from MyTable
```

[**SOURCE**](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/max_query2_2007.php)